# parse from a huge txt file and write each output in separate files

Tags: python, parsing, design-patterns, multiline

How can I extract a multiline string from a huge txt file and to write each found pattern in a separate file?

An example extract from source file (example.txt):

```
RIG 1C 0
RIC 1 F
RIB F F
RIB A F
RIB O O
RIC 2 C
RIB J J
RIB C J
RIB D C
RIB Z D
RIB R Z
RIB I I
RIB S S
RIC 3 Y
RIB Y Y
RIB M Y
RIB L M
RIB H L
RIB K H
RIB B K
RIB W B
RIB Q W
RIB V Q
RIB N V
RIB G B
RIB T B
RIB X X
RIG 1C 1
RIC 1 F
RIB F F
RIB A F
RIB O O
RIC 2 C
RIB J J
RIB C J
RIB D C
RIB Z D
RIB R Z
RIB I I
RIB S S
RIC 3 Y
RIB Y Y
RIB M Y
RIB L M
RIB H L
RIB K H
RIB B K
RIB W B
RIB Q W
RIB V Q
RIB N V
RIB G B
RIB T B
RIB X X
RIG DE 0
RIC 1 F
RIB F F
RIC 2 C
RIB C C
```

Pattern is from RIG to RIG

this means first file RIG1C0.txt contains:

```
RIG 1C 0
RIC 1 F
RIB F F
RIB A F
RIB O O
RIC 2 C
RIB J J
RIB C J
RIB D C
RIB Z D
RIB R Z
RIB I I
RIB S S
RIC 3 Y
RIB Y Y
RIB M Y
RIB L M
RIB H L
RIB K H
RIB B K
RIB W B
RIB Q W
RIB V Q
RIB N V
RIB G B
RIB T B
RIB X X
```

second file RIG1C1.txt :

```
RIG 1C 1
RIC 1 F
RIB F F
RIB A F
RIB O O
RIC 2 C
RIB J J
RIB C J
RIB D C
RIB Z D
RIB R Z
RIB I I
RIB S S
RIC 3 Y
RIB Y Y
RIB M Y
RIB L M
RIB H L
RIB K H
RIB B K
RIB W B
RIB Q W
RIB V Q
RIB N V
RIB G B
RIB T B
RIB X X
```

and so on.

I heard something about RegEx

Is someone able to help me?

Comment: Doesn't sound like you need regexes for this. Iterate line-by-line, check if line starts with `RIG`, and if so, start a new file and write all the following lines to it until the next time you see a line start with `RIG`, and then repeat the previous stuff by creating a new file, etc. Also, if you don't need to do this with Python, this is basically a one-line command in the shell.

Comment: thanks wkl   ... I like this approach .. will try ...

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Method without Regex and just python builtin modules:

```
from pathlib import Path
# File Contents as String
originalFile=Path("path/to/file.txt").read_text()
for i,subFileContents in enumerate(originalFile.split("RIG")):
    # First RIG could be empty String
    if subFileContents:
        # Attach the searched Keyword again
        temp="RIG"+subFileContents
        # format String zeropadded number exactly 5 digits
        with open(f"RIG1C{i:05}.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(temp)
```

Comment: wow jack ... this is exactly what I'm looking for ... many many thanks to you!